How to get rid of 'Found duplicates in MetaData.' message in Obsidian
I recently installed TickTickSync in Obsidian (v1.5.12) and after connecting to my TickTick account and pulling my TickTick tasks into Obsidian, I get a black panel that appears on the right hand side of my Obsidian app every few minutes. The panel is titled 'Found duplicates in MetaData.' The panel lists a bunch of recurring TickTick tasks. Is there any way I can get rid of this panel from appearing every few minutes?
I can click the panel and it disappears, but it always comes back a few minutes later. I changed the timing of the sync between TickTick and Obsidian to 12 hours, but the problem persists.
Found duplicates in MetaData
